# jQuery ReferenceError: Can't find variable: events

Tags: jquery

I have `JQuery` and added in script tag as

```
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But still, I am getting following error when some action performed.

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: events

Code:

```
jQuery(events).trigger('dizmo.resized', [dizmo.getWidth(), dizmo.getHeight()]);
jQuery(events).trigger('dizmo.turned', ['front']);
```

Comment: then the variable events isn't declared. Make sure it is declared and that it can be used at this point in your code. For more help create a minimal working example where we can see what's happening.

Comment: I have declared events as object
var events = {};

It worked for me thanks